# Add multiple SSH keys using ansible

Tags: ssh, batch-processing, ssh-keys, ansible

I have written an ansible script to remove SSH keys from remote servers:

```yaml
---
- name: "Add keys to the authorized_keys of the user ubuntu"
  user: ubuntu
  hosts: www
  tasks:
  - name: "Remove key #1"
    authorized_key: user=ubuntu key="{{ item }}" state=absent
    with_file:
     - id_rsa_number_one.pub
  - name: "Remove key #2"
    authorized_key: user=ubuntu key="{{ item }}" state=absent
    with_file:
     - id_rsa_number_two.pub
...
```

Adding each file as a different task is preposterous, so I have tried using [`with_fileglob`](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-fileglobs):

```yaml
  - name: "Remove all keys at once"
    authorized_key: user=ubuntu key="{{ item }}" state=absent
    with_fileglob:
      - /Users/adamatan/ansible/id_rsa*.pub
```

But this fails with lines like this:

> failed: [www.example.com] =>
>   (item=/Users/adamatan/ansible/id_rsa_one.pub) => {"failed": true,
>   "item": "/Users/adamatan/ansible/id_rsa_one.pub"} msg: invalid key
>   specified: /Users/adamatan/ansible/id_rsa_one.pub

The same key file is successfully removed using a unique task, but fails when it's a part of a `fileglob`.

**How can I batch add or remove SSH keys using ansible?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you are only getting the filenames using `with_fileglob`, but `with_file` retrieves the *contents* of the file. And the authorized_key module requires the actual key.

So you should still loop by using `with_fileglob`, but instead of sending the filename to the "key=" parameter, you should use the [file lookup plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_lookups.html#intro-to-lookups-getting-file-contents)).

```
- name: "Remove all keys at once"
    authorized_key: user=ubuntu key="{{ lookup('file', item) }}" state=absent
    with_fileglob:
      - /Users/adamatan/ansible/id_rsa*.pub
```

Comment: So this modification works great for bulk updating/removing entries. Here's my issue - I have keys on servers from someone who is no longer here. How can I purge and overwrite the authorized_keys file with my master list of active keys? When I run this script it removes (if absent) my active keys or adds (if present) but it never removes the keys for which is not in my *.pub files.

Comment: @Valien for multiple exclusive keys, see the example in this [pull request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/pull/4167/files).

Comment: You could also create `~/.ssh/` and copy over static `authorized_keys` files for all the users in some host groups. In that case you would have full control over file contents.