# Is it possible to use Ansible authorized_key exclusive with multiple keys?

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, authorized-keys

I'm fairly new in using Ansible and have been reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26203345/add-multiple-ssh-keys-using-ansible) and google and haven't found an answer yet.

My scenario is that I have 1 user on a server but 2-3 different pub keys that need to put in it's authorized_keys file.

I can successfully remove all keys, or add all keys with this script:

```
---
  - hosts: all

 tasks:
  - name: update SSH keys
    authorized_key:
     user: <user>
     key: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
     state: present
     #exclusive: yes
    with_fileglob:
      - ../files/pub_keys/*.pub
```

With the `present` flag it reads and adds all the keys. With the `absent` flag it removes all keys listed.

Problem is that I have an old key that is only on the server and I want to remove/overwrite it and for future deployments overwrite any unauthorized keys that might be on the server and not in my playbook.

With the `exclusive` flag it only takes the last key and adds it. This would be fantastic if it would loop and recusively add all the keys. If there is a way to do this in Ansible I have not found it.

Is there any way to loop over pub files and use the `exclusive` option at the same time?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Is there any way to loop over pub files and use the exclusive option at the same time?*

No. There is a note about loops and exclusive in the [docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html):

> **exclusive:** Whether to remove all other non-specified keys from the authorized_keys file. Multiple keys can be specified in a single key string value by separating them by newlines.
>   This option is not loop aware, so if you use with_ , it will be exclusive per iteration of the loop, if you want multiple keys in the file you need to pass them all to key in a single batch as mentioned above.

So you need to join all your keys and send all them at once.
Something like this:

```
- name: update SSH keys
  authorized_key:
    user: <user>
    key: "{{ lookup('pipe','cat ../files/pub_keys/*.pub') }}"
    state: present
    exclusive: yes
```

**Check this code before running in production!**

Comment: Oh man, you're a lifesaver! Works great! I just discovered the `lookup` stuff but was trying to make sense of it. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to be careful and put EOL at the end of each pub key file. Otherwise, keys might be concatenated in a single line.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to avoid the `pipe` lookup (e.g., because the path is not relative to the role), you can also use a combination of `file` and `fileglob` lookups:

```
- name: update SSH keys
  authorized_key:
    user: <user>
    key:  "{% for key in lookup('fileglob', 'pub_keys/*.pub').split(',') %}{{ lookup('file', key) ~ '\n'}}{% endfor %}"
    state: present
    exclusive: yes
```

Comment: Even better when you use "query" than "lookup" - this way you avoid need for "split" and get protected against not existing paths:

`key: "{% for key in query('fileglob', 'pub_keys/*') %}{{ lookup('file', key) ~ '\n'}}{% endfor %}"`

Answer (score 5):

If your keep your users inside a variable you might use this:

```
---

- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - roles/users/vars/main.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Allow other users to login to the account
      authorized_key:
        user: user_name
        exclusive: yes
        key: "{{ developers|map(attribute='publish_ssh_key')|join('\n') }}"
```

The `roles/users/vars/main.yml` looks like this:

```
---

developers:
  - name: user1
    publish_ssh_key: ssh-rsa AAAA...
  - name: user2
    publish_ssh_key: ssh-rsa AAAA...
```

Comment: This only adds the last key, but according to the docs, it should work "Multiple keys can be specified in a single key string value by separating them by newlines" http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html Do you know why it's broken?

Comment: @goetzc I don't know :-(

Comment: Hey, it was that I had test keys which where identical, just with a different comment, and then Ansible only added the last one :)

Answer (score 1):

I created simple playbook where I needed specific path for icewarp users.

```
---

- name: configure icewarp user with proper keys and sudo rights
  hosts: all
  remote_user: root
# tasks file for iw_ssh_keys
  tasks:

  - name: Check that the /opt/icewarp/.ssh/authorized_keys exists
    stat:
      path: /opt/icewarp/.ssh/authorized_keys
    register: stat_result

  - name: Create the file, if /opt/icewarp/.ssh/authorized_keys doesnt exist already
    file:
       path: /opt/icewarp/.ssh/authorized_keys
       state: touch
       mode: '0600'
    when: not stat_result.stat.exists

  - name: Set authorized_keys, removing all undefined ones
    authorized_key:
      user: icewarp
      key: '{{ item }}'
      state: present
      path: /opt/icewarp/.ssh/authorized_keys 
      exclusive: True
    with_file:
      - ../public_keys/authorized_keys

  - name: change user shell to bash 
    become: yes
    user:
      name: icewarp
      shell: /bin/bash

  - name: Configuring /etc/sudoers.d/icewarp
    community.general.sudoers:
      name: icewarp
      state: present
      user: icewarp
      commands: /usr/bin/journalctl *, /usr/bin/less /var/log/*, /usr/bin/grep * /var/log*
```

Answer (score 0):

as I wrote over at this other answer ([Ansible - managing multiple SSH keys for multiple users & roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483303/ansible-managing-multiple-ssh-keys-for-multiple-users-roles/53104809#53104809)) this is the way that I solved this issue for my use-case. Perhaps it is useful here?

I pass an array of filenames in a variable to my `user-account` role.  The role then gets the contents of each of these files, appends them together into a newline-separated string, then finally sets this value to be the ssh-key for the new user.

.

The playbook file:

```
- hosts: aws-node1
  roles:
    - { role: user-account, username: 'developer1', ssh_public_keyfiles: ['peter-sshkey.pub', 'paul-sshkey.pub'] }
```

.

The role definition for `user-account`:

```
- name: add user
  user:
    name: "{{username}}"


- name: lookup ssh pubkeys from keyfiles and create ssh_pubkeys_list
  set_fact:
    ssh_pubkeys_list: "{{ lookup('file', item) }}"
  with_items:
    "{{ssh_public_keyfiles}}"
  register: ssh_pubkeys_results_list


- name: iterate over ssh_pubkeys_list and join into a string
  set_fact:
    ssh_pubkeys_string: "{{ ssh_pubkeys_results_list.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.ssh_pubkeys_list') | list | join('\n') }}"


- name: update SSH authorized_keys for user {{ username }} with contents of ssh_pubkeys_string
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ username }}"
    key: "{{ ssh_pubkeys_string }}"
    state: present
    exclusive: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Same basic concept as the previous answers but only using variables and pulling the keys from a url like github or gitlab.

```yaml
#Vars
ssh_users:
  - user1
  - user2
ssh_key_urls: "{{ ssh_users | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'https://key_server/\\1.keys') | list }}"
authorized_keys: "{% for u in ssh_key_urls %}{{ lookup('url', u, split_lines=False) }}\n{% endfor %}"

#task
- name: setup authorized_keys
  authorized_key:
    key: "{{ authorized_keys }}"
    state: present
    exclusive: true
```