# ansible Iterate over list in list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to adopt the task in the last answer from this post [Ansible - managing multiple SSH keys for multiple users & roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483303/ansible-managing-multiple-ssh-keys-for-multiple-users-roles/53104809#53104809)

My variable looks like:

```
provisioning_user:
  - name: ansible
    state: present
    ssh_public_keyfiles:
      - ansible.pub
      - user.pub
  - name: foo
    state: present
    ssh_public_keyfiles:
      - bar.pub
      - key.pub
```

and my code looks like

```
- name: lookup ssh pubkeys from keyfiles and create ssh_pubkeys_list
  set_fact:
    ssh_pubkeys_list: "{{ lookup('file', item.ssh_public_keyfiles) }}"
  loop: "{{ provisioning_user }}"
  register: ssh_pubkeys_results_list
```

I want to store keys under the files directory and assign them with the variable to different users so that when a key changes, i only have to change the file and run the playbook instead of changing it in any hostvars file where the old key is used. But I get the following error and dont know how to solve it. I want to do this for every user defined in `provisioning_user`

```
fatal: [cloud.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => 
  msg: 'An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin ''file''. Error was a <class ''AttributeError''>, original message: ''list'' object has no attribute ''startswith''. ''list'' object has no attribute ''startswith'''
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` lookup reads the content of a single file, but you're passing it a *list*. That's not going to work, and is the direct cause of the error message you've reported.

You're also using both `set_fact` and `register` in the same task, which doesn't make much sense: the whole point of a `set_fact` task is to create a new variable; you shouldn't need to `register` the result.

Your life is going to be complicated by the fact that each user can have multiple key *files*. We need to build a data structure that maps each user name to a list of keys; we can do that like this:

```
- name: lookup ssh pubkeys from keyfiles
  set_fact:
    pubkeys: >-
      {{
        pubkeys |
        combine({
          item.0.name: pubkeys.get(item.0.name, []) + [lookup('file', item.1)]})
      }}
  vars:
    pubkeys: {}
  loop: "{{ provisioning_user|subelements('ssh_public_keyfiles') }}"
```

This creates the variable `pubkeys`, which is a dictionary that maps usernames to keys. Assuming that our `provisioning_user` variable looks like this:

```
provisioning_user:
  - name: ansible
    state: present
    ssh_public_keyfiles:
      - ansible.pub
      - user.pub
  - name: foo
    state: present
    ssh_public_keyfiles:
      - bar.pub
      - key.pub
  - name: bar
    state: present
    ssh_public_keyfiles: []
```

After running the above task, `pubkeys` looks like:

```
"pubkeys": {
    "ansible": [
        "ssh-rsa ...",
        "ssh-rsa ..."
    ],
    "foo": [
        "ssh-rsa ...",
        "ssh-rsa ..."
    ]
}
```

We can use `pubkeys` in our `authorized_keys` task like this:

```
- name: test key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ '\n'.join(pubkeys[item.name]) }}"
    comment: "{{ item.key_comment | default('managed by ansible') }}"
    state: "{{ item.state | default('true') }}"
    exclusive: "{{ item.key_exclusive | default('true') }}"
    key_options: "{{ item.key_options | default(omit) }}"
    manage_dir: "{{ item.manage_dir | default('true') }}"
  loop: "{{ provisioning_user }}"
  when: item.name in pubkeys
```

---

I think your life would be easier if you were to rethink how you're managing keys. Instead of allowing each user to have a list of multiple key files, have a *single* public key file for each user -- named after the username -- that may contain multiple public keys.

That reduces your `provisioning_user` data to:

```
provisioning_user:
  - name: ansible
    state: present
  - name: foo
    state: present
  - name: bar
    state: present
```

And in our `files/` directory, we have:

```
files
├── ansible.keys
└── foo.keys
```

You no longer need the `set_fact` task at all, and the `authorized_keys` task looks like:

```
- name: test key
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.name }}"
    key: "{{ keys }}"
    comment: "{{ item.key_comment | default('managed by ansible') }}"
    state: "{{ item.state | default('true') }}"
    exclusive: "{{ item.key_exclusive | default('true') }}"
    key_options: "{{ item.key_options | default(omit) }}"
    manage_dir: "{{ item.manage_dir | default('true') }}"
  when: >-
    ('files/%s.keys' % item.name) is exists
  vars:
    keys: "{{ lookup('file', '%s.keys' % item.name) }}"
  loop: "{{ provisioning_user }}"
```

Note that in the above the `when` condition requires an explicit path, while the `file` lookup will implicitly look in the `files` directory.

These changes dramatically simplify your playbook.

Comment: Thanks larsks for this very detailed answer, this truely solves my problem. I thought a lot about managing keys and this came out at the end. I need this task to be flexible and i deploy the same keys to different users. I absolutely dont want to change the same key in different files, I want only one source of truth, one key, one file. When I need to rotate the key I need to rotate it on every machine, and instead of changing all the files for the users I only want to change the one .pub file

Comment: can you tell me how I can learn about building such complex structures like the pubkeys variable? I don't know what to google or how that is named

Comment: The `pubkeys` variable is a "dictionary", but I'm not sure that searching for that term is going to yield practical results. Several parts of the Ansible documentation are probably relevant ([1](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html), [2](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/complex_data_manipulation.html)), and you'll find a variety of other articles online if you look for "ansible data structures". Being familiar with  Python definitely helps, because Ansible variables are ultimately Python variables.