# Ansible: check whether a file contains only given lines, no more

Tags: security, ansible, ssh-keys, system-administration

By using Ansible, I try to make sure that the `.ssh/authorized_keys` files of our servers contain only a given set of ssh keys. No matter the arrangement.

1. If one is missing, add it (no problem, `lineinfile`)
2. If someone else sneaked in an extra key (which is not in the "with_items" list), remove it and return some warning, or something. Well... "changed" could be acceptable too, but it would be nice to differentiate somehow the "missing" and "sneaked in" lines.

The first part is easy:

```
- name: Ensure ssh authorized_keys contains the right users
  lineinfile:
    path: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0600
    state: present
    line: '{{ item }}'

  with_items:
    - ssh-rsa AABBCC112233... root@someserver.com
    - ssh-rsa DDEEFF112233... user@anothersomeserver.com
```

But the second part looks more tricky. At least to get it done with short and elegant code.

Any ideas?

Comment: lineinfile is not your friend.

Comment: why not just always over-write the target with the source file?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan: That could work, but then I wouldn't know if some key was missing or if there was some extra one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [authorized_key_module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/authorized_key_module.html) and it has `exclusive` option.
But pay attention that `exclusive` doesn't work with `with_items`.

Use something like this:

```
- name: Ensure ssh authorized_keys contains the right users
  authorized_key:
    user: root
    state: present
    exclusive: yes
    key: '{{ ssh_keys | join("\n") }}'
  vars:
    ssh_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AABBCC112233... root@someserver.com
      - ssh-rsa DDEEFF112233... user@anothersomeserver.com
```

*Test before use!*

If you have keys in files, you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38879787/2795592) answer useful.

Comment: Wow! that is nice! But, how do you define the ssh_keys variable? I tried with a multiline string, and it just splits it into characters with newlines... Would that be equivalent to using a key file with the "with_file" option?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to define it. Also if you have keys in files, I've added a link to other answer.

Comment: Thank you! that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!